# Mapping statistics from bam file using bbtools and sambamba

Tags: rna-seq, samtools, bash, java, sambamba

Below are the statistics for RNA-seq mapped and unmapped paired-end reads to rice genome using reformat.sh from bbtools on bam files. It gives 77% mapped and 5% unmapped, what about the remaining 18% reads? How I can get information for all reads?

```
Command;
reformat.sh in=Leaf_T1_F_R10_S1_L001.bam out=Leaf_T1_F_R10_S1_L001.mapped.bam, mappedonly


Unspecified format for output Leaf_T1_F_R10_S1_L001.mapped.bam,; defaulting to fastq.
Found sambamba.
Input is being processed as unpaired
Input:                   67471075 reads           9312399845 bases
Output:                 52020538 reads (77.10%) 7208830835 bases (77.41%)

Time:                         171.212 seconds.
Reads Processed:      67471k 394.08k reads/sec
Bases Processed:       9312m 54.39m bases/sec

For unmapped read;
Command;
reformat.sh in=Leaf_T1_F_R10_S1_L001.bam out=Leaf_T1_F_R10_S1_L001.unmapped.bam, unmappedonly

Unspecified format for output Leaf_T1_F_R10_S1_L001.unmapped.bam,; defaulting to fastq.
Found sambamba.
Input is being processed as unpaired
Input:                   67471075 reads           9312399845 bases
Output:                 3435326 reads (5.09%) 465456267 bases (5.00%)

Time:                         142.978 seconds.
Reads Processed:      67471k 471.90k reads/sec
Bases Processed:       9312m 65.13m bases/sec
```

With sambamba; Can I say 94.91% reads are mapped and 5.09% are unmapped?

```
67471075 + 0 in total (QC-passed reads + QC-failed reads)
12015211 + 0 secondary
0 + 0 supplementary
0 + 0 duplicates
64035749 + 0 mapped (94.91%:N/A)
55455864 + 0 paired in sequencing
27727932 + 0 read1
27727932 + 0 read2
51006046 + 0 properly paired (91.98%:N/A)
51419222 + 0 with itself and mate mapped
601316 + 0 singletons (1.08%:N/A)
263816 + 0 with mate mapped to a different chr
237111 + 0 with mate mapped to a different chr (mapQ>=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `samtools flagstat` or `sambamba flagstat` to get similar type of information about your bam file. It may be easier to interpret. Both of these tools can be installed using `conda` if needed.

**EDIT:**

Yes, the results of `sambamba flagstat` you showed in your edited post indicate exactly what you said: `94.91%` mapped and `100% - 94.91% = 5.09%` unmapped:

```
64035749 + 0 mapped (94.91%:N/A)
```

Comment: Hi Timur, Thanks, I have added the results from sambamba as well, I think it gives the accurate result. Could you please respond to query related to sambamba result?

Comment: @bioinfonext Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment than an answer... In my opinion the terminology is a bit confusing since the term *reads* actually refers to a more generic *records*.

Look at this test file:

```
samtools view test.sam | cut -f 1-4
HSQ9103:404:C6F0VANXX:1:2208:4363:50381 0   chr7    5529094
HSQ9103:404:C6F0VANXX:1:2208:4363:50381 0   chr7    5529194
HSQ9103:404:C6F0VANXX:1:2208:4363:50381 0   chr7    5529194
HSQ9103:404:C6F0VANXX:1:2208:4363:50381 0   chr7    5529194
HSQ9103:403:C6F0HANXX:8:2215:4792:20065 4   chr7    5529871
```

I would say that here there are 5 records (of which 4 are alignments) but only 2 **reads**.

`samtools flagstat` reports 80% mapping rate but maybe I would say this is 50%.

```
samtools flagstat test.sam 
5 + 0 in total (QC-passed reads + QC-failed reads)
0 + 0 secondary
0 + 0 supplementary
0 + 0 duplicates
4 + 0 mapped (80.00% : N/A)
0 + 0 paired in sequencing
0 + 0 read1
0 + 0 read2
0 + 0 properly paired (N/A : N/A)
0 + 0 with itself and mate mapped
0 + 0 singletons (N/A : N/A)
0 + 0 with mate mapped to a different chr
0 + 0 with mate mapped to a different chr (mapQ>=5)
```